# Параллелизм в Haskell

Tags: haskell, распараллеливание

Передо мной стоит задача следующего плана: Требуется написать код на Haskell для вычисления определенного интеграла с заданной точностью и с заданной степенью параллелизма. 
Для реализации параллельных вычислений использовался пакет Parallel.
Файл собирается следующим образом:

```
ghc -O2 -threaded --make example.lhs
```

Запускаю следующим образом:

```
./example.exe +RTS -NC
```

где C - количество процессоров.

Проблема состоит в том, что начиная с 3х процессоров время выполнения, в среднем, не уменьшается, а иногда увеличивается, что странно (процессор intel core i7 950). Вот пример:

1. 0.3909979s
2. 0.2869971s
3. 0.2879952s
4. 0.3300107s
5. 0.3399981s
6. 0.3509944s

Вот код программы:

```hs
>   import Control.Parallel
>   import Data.Time
>   import Control.DeepSeq
>   import Control.Parallel.Strategies
>
>   calculate :: Double -> Double -> Double -> Int -> Double
>   calculate a b eps p = calc a b (eps / (fromIntegral p)) p ((b - a) / (fromIntegral p))
>
>   calc :: Double -> Double -> Double -> Int -> Double -> Double
>   calc a b eps p h = let chunks = [ integrate (a + (h * (fromIntegral i))) (a + (h * (fromIntegral i + 1))) h eps (trap (a + (h * (fromIntegral i))) (a + (h * (fromIntegral i + 1))) h) (trap (a + (h * (fromIntegral i))) (a + (h * (fromIntegral i + 1))) (h / 2.0))
>                                   | i <- [0..p-1] ] `using` parList rdeepseq in sum chunks
>
>   integrate :: Double -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Double
>   integrate a b step eps previous current | runge previous current eps == True = current
>                                           | otherwise = integrate a b (step / 2.0) eps (trap a b (step / 2.0)) (trap a b (step / 4.0))
>
>   trap :: Double -> Double -> Double -> Double
>   trap a b step = step * (((f a + f b) / 2) + summ (a + step) (b - step) step)
>
>   summ :: Double -> Double -> Double -> Double 
>   summ a b step | a > b = 0
>                 | a == b = f a
>                 | otherwise = (f a + f b) + summ (a + step) (b - step) step
>
>   f :: Double -> Double
>   f x = sin(x) + 10
>
>   runge :: Double -> Double -> Double -> Bool
>   runge h1 h2 eps | abs(h1 - h2)/3 < eps = True
>                   | otherwise = False
>
>   main = do
>       start <- getCurrentTime
>       print (calculate 0 360 0.0000001 80)
>       end <- getCurrentTime
>       print (diffUTCTime end start)
```

Нормальное ли это поведение или я неправильно пытаюсь распараллелить задачу? Прошу помочь разобраться.

Comment: В коде есть несколько проблем, которые делают его нестабильным (вплоть до зависания), а все замеры - бессмысленными. Хотя на моем железе и конкретно с этими параметрами все работает предсказуемо - при -N4 максимальная производительность. при больших/меньших - падает.

Comment: @extrn Не могли бы вы указать на эти проблемы?

Comment: 1) `summ` не оптимизирован - большая часть времени работы тратится на создание ненужных `thunk`ов. 2) там же `a == b = f a` в большинстве случаев недостижимое условие 3) Для быстрорастущих функций из за потери точности алгоритм может и не завершиться 4) если и завершится, из за потенциально экспоненциального роста количества шагов (*2, *4 итд), на некоторых чанках может занять время в разы превосходящее время работы всей остальной программы - значит распараллеливание не сработает. Это навскидку